# Migrate/copy data from postgres to vertica

Tags: python, postgresql, copy, database-migration, vertica

I'm trying to migrate/copy data from postgres to vertica using python3 (if there are also other user-friendly ways, I'd be glad to hear them). Problem is that the code below works only when I copy a column of data from postgres. In case when I copy more than one column, it migrates nothing.i.e. created in vertica table is empty.

How can I migrate entire table from postgres to vertica?

```
conn = psycopg2.connect()

input = io.StringIO()
cur_postrgres = conn.cursor()
cur_postrgres.copy_expert('''COPY (SELECT id, date from table_1) TO STDOUT;''', input)
cur_postrgres.close()

cur_vertica.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_1_temp;")
cur_vertica.connection.commit()
cur_vertica.execute('''CREATE TABLE table_1_temp (
id BIGINT, date TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE);''')
cur_vertica.connection.commit()

#cur_vertica.stdin = input
#input.seek(0)

cur_vertica.copy('''COPY table_1_temp FROM STDIN NULL AS 'null' ''',  input.getvalue())
cur_vertica.execute("COMMIT;")
cur_vertica.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default delimiter in postgresql copy is a tab, I believe. The default delimiter for vertica is a pipe. You may need to specify `DELIMITER E'\t'` on the vertica copy, or specify `DELIMITER '|'` on the postgresql one.

Most likely the data is getting rejected for not having enough columns.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to copy a Postgres database to Vertica is to use `pg_dump`.  This creates a tar with tab-separated text datafiles and a SQL program that you can edit and execute in Vertica.

This can be useful if there are many tables that need to be created.  The SQL contains statements like CREATE TABLE, ADD INDEX, CREATE SEQUENCE, etc. for each table, and generates COPY statements to load each data file.

Vertica is based on PostgresQL so the dialects are similar.  The `restore.sql` that it generates is almost perfect, you just need to delete statements that are not relevant, maybe change the schema name, and refine the `COPY` statements.

```
pg_dump --format=tar --dbname=mydb --username=myuser --no-owner --verbose --no-privileges > mydata.tar
```

Optionally compress the tar before export

```
zip mydata.tar.zip mydata.tar
```

Copy the tarball to a working directory on the Vertica machine

```
scp -i ~/.ssh/secret.pem mydata.tar.zip  mydata.tar.zip  myuser@123.456.345:/data
```

Log into the instance, unzip the tarball:

```
 ssh -i ~/.ssh/secret.pem myuser@123.456.345:/data
 unzip mydata.tar.zip
 tar -xvf mydata.tar
```

Now edit the `restore.sql` file appropriately.  I found I needed to:

- delete a bunch of stuff at the top like `SET statement_timeout = 0;` and `COMMENT ON EXTENSION plpgsql` that isn't relevant to Vertica
- delete one of the two `COPY` statements it generates, one from `STDIN` and one from a file
- edit the `COPY` statement to add vertica-specific things like `DELIMITER AS E'\t'  NULL AS '\N'  ABORT ON ERROR;`

After that, importing was just executing that file in Vertica:

```
\i restore_modified.sql
```